# Vertically center text in div, with minimal padding above and below it (spectre.css)

Tags: css, spectre.css

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/notayam/4mLzus0y/

I set top-padding and bottom-padding to zero, and the layout display of the box model in the inspector shows 0 above and below, but as you can see from the jsfiddle there's still blank space there. And furthermore it's not centered vertically.

Adding `vertical-align: middle !important;` didn't help.

I got it centered vertically by trying different values for `line-height`, but that doesn't get rid of the unwanted padding above and below the text.

I dug out some older code that had a similar situation (using bootstrap) that I had muddled around with long enough to get it *roughly* like what I want. It used `display: inline-block` where this uses `block`. and although I have no idea if that might help I tried including `display: inline-block !important;` here. But it still shows up as `block` in the inspector; it shows both my css and spectre css specifying `inline-block`, but then `block` on the element. I couldn't figure out where that was coming from or why the override didn't work.

Tips on debugging CSS more efficiently would be very welcome. I really just need to get a table to display a whole bunch of data as compactly as possible, and would love to get that to work and never have to go near CSS ever again.

The rest of the app uses Python 3/Airium/Bottle, if that might matter. Running on Firefox 100.0.2 on MacOS 12.1. I'll only be running it locally so support for other browsers doesn't matter to me.

Comment: What are you actually trying to center? The btn-group or each btn?

Comment: Center the text within the btn

Comment: For that, all you'll need is remove the style you've for the button. When the style under .btn, the text appears to be on center.

Comment: Yes it's vertically centered by default, but what I want to do is remove the extra padding above and below the text *and* center the text vertically. Something is overriding `padding-top: 0 !important` and `padding-bottom: 0 !important` but I can't figure out what's doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.btn {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    height: unset !important;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. That centers the btn-group vertically on the page, but I want to center the text vertically within the btn cell (and also get rid of the extra padding above and below the text, so that the row is more compact).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/notayam/4mLzus0y/

Comment: I guess that's what you were looking for? There is no extra padding at the top and bottom?

Comment: Works better than anything else I've tried! Thanks. The modified jsfiddle is above. I'd like to squeeze out just a bit more of the vertical padding but this is good.

Comment: With the current setup, there is no padding applied on top and bottom, if you'll check in the computed column in the dev tools, the only padding applied is on the sides. The only thing that governs the gap now is the content height, which in this case will be font-size. I hope I could understand what else you were trying to achieve with this.

Comment: By padding I don't mean CSS padding, I mean the white space above and below the text within the cell. I'd rather have a bit less, but your solution is far better than anything else I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood what you want, but here is some solution:

```css
.btn-group .btn {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  /* This is to clear line height */
  line-height: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

We can transform your buttons to flex boxes, so you then can control height, and have no vertical padding.

Comment: That centers the text within the btn cell, but then is there any way to get rid of most of the padding above and below the text within the cell? The btn-group is in a table, and they make the table rows taller than they would be otherwise.

Comment: Changing padding-top and padding-bottom to 10px instead of zero doesn't seem to change anything, although larger values do. What's overriding padding-top and padding-bottom here?